# comparing values in two dictionaries in python

Tags: python

I am stuck in the middle of my coding because of this:
I have two dictionaries as follows:

```
a = {0:['1'],1:['0','-3']}
b = {'box 4': ['0 and 2', '0 and -3', ' 0 and -1', ' 2 and 3'], 'box 0': [' 1 ', ' 1 and 4 ', ' 3 and 4']
```

I want to find if the values in the first dictionaries match the values in the second and if it does, I want to return the matched key and values in dictionary b.

For example: The result of the comparison will return `box4`, ['0','-3'] here as `['0','-3']` is an item in `a` and it has been found also in `b` `['0 and -3']`, however if only '3' has been found I don't want it to return anything as there's no values match it. the result will also return `box0`, `['1']` as it is an item in `a` and it has been found also in `b`.

Any ideas ? I appreciate any helps.

Comment: its not clear can you give expected output??

Comment: more expected outputs have been added, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You say, "the result of the comparison will return box4 here as ['0','-3'] is an item in a and it has been found also in b ['0 and -3'],". I do not see `'0 and -3'` in b.

Also, your question is not clear enough. Your code snippets are not complete and you have presented just once case here.

Nevertheless, I will make the mistake of assuming that you want something like this

```
normalized_values = set([" and ".join(tokens) for tokens in a.values()])
for k in b:
    if normalized_values.intersection(set(b[k])):
        print k
```

Answer (score 0):

here you go: its simple coded,

```
>>> a_values = a.values()
>>> for x,y in b.items():
...     for i in y:
...         i = i.strip()
...         if len(i)>1:
...             i = i.split()[::2]
...             if i in a_values:
...                 print x,i
...         else:
...             if list(i) in a_values:
...                 print x,list(i)
box 4 ['0', '-3']
box 0 ['1']
```

pythonic way:

```
>>> [ [x,i] for x,y in b.items() for i in y if re.findall('-?\d',i) in a_values ]
[['box 4', ' 0 and -3'], ['box 0', ' 1 ']]
```